# Unable to login after uninstalling gnome keyring

Tags: login

I Uninstalled gnome keyring with sudo apt autoremove gnome-keyring. Then I restarted my machine. Now when I enter the password, the login screen comes back again. It basically doesn't let me log in. What are my options right now?

Comment: You can try installing gnome keyring again by logging in through a terminal session. In the login screen press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, then login using your username and password. You will need to be connected to the internet (if you're connected by ethernet, it should work by default), and run the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring`. If you use wifi or other modes for internet connection, you may need to connect it using specific commands,

Comment: This is what I did already. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Chnage to the text console by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in.
Then you can do:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Most likely more packages (like gdm3 or ubuntu-session) have been removed due to your actions and dependencies to gnome-keyring. 
These will get reinstalled too wby using the ubuntu-desktop meta package.